# Unable to call dotnet methods from powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to call the Start method of a System.Diagnostics.Process. I've seen many other examples on the internet doing that exact same however when I run my code:

```
$process = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process

$config.variables.properties | foreach {
  $process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Set_Item($_.name, $_.value)
}

$process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
$process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"
$process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/config:$configPath\${name}ApplicationHost.config \site:$name"

$process.Start()
```

I get this meaningless error:

```
Exception calling "Start" with "0" argument(s): "The parameter is incorrect"
At C:\Users\critc\Source\run-iisexpress.ps1:67 char:1
+ $started = $process.Start() | Out-Null
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Win32Exception
```

This method has a 0 parameter overload. Infact if I drop the parentheses from the call powershell in it's infinite wisdom tells me theres a zero parameter overload

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
bool Start()
```

Powershell is trolling me! Originally I was creating a ProcessStartInfo instance and trying to pass it to the static Process.Start method and I was getting the same error (except it said `with "1" argument(s)`)

**UPDATE**

Heres my updated code that works.

```
$process = new-object System.Diagnostics.Process

Get-Member -inputObject $config.variables -memberType Properties | foreach {
  $value = $config.variables | select -exp $_.name
  $process.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables.Set_Item($_.name, $value)
}

$process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false
$process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe"
$process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/config:`"$configPath\${name}ApplicationHost.config`" /site:$name"

$started = $process.Start()
if ($started) {
  $process.WaitForExit()
}
```

Comment: $process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false should be $process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = $false, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidBrabant yes you're correct how that doesn't seem to have been the cause of my woes

Comment: here's everything as a gist if anyones interested - https://gist.github.com/worldspawn/ed3e16accbdefaa8ee35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something tells me your parameters are incorrect, and you have a space in `$configPath`.  But that is just a hunch...  It would be better if you supplied values of `$configPath` and `$name` in your question.

What happens if you use:

```
$process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/config:`"$configPath\${name}ApplicationHost.config`" /site:`"$name`""
```

Comment: I made that change, I also noticed my site slash was in the wrong direction. However that didn't resolve the problem, but it got me thinking I should try and comment out the other lines of setup and see if anything changes. It turns out my environment variable lines are somehow causing the problem.

Comment: My environment variable loop was completely broken :D Thats what happens when u copy paste off the web! It was setting blank named variables. I've updated my answer with the corrected loop, you got me on the right path so you can have the points. Thanks